# Where should the stone left on a grave come from?

Tags: minhag, cemetery-grave

I will be traveling for an unveiling soon and intend to leave a stone at the grave. Since I will be traveling I have the ability to bring the stone from where I live or to find a stone near the cemetery (there is a rocky river across the street from the cemetry.)

Are there halachic or minhagic opinions about which is the preferred option, to bring a stone from my home or to use a stone local to the cemetery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus2 67:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=506&hilite=) only mentions placing a stone or some grass on the gravestone. There is no mention of a preference as to where the stone comes from. This leads me to believe that there is no preferred option.